You and a friend play a game. You both pick 5 cards from a set containing numbers 1 through 10. The winner has the largest sum, can you tie?
This is a puzzle I thought up. It was inspired by the Mario Party 7 minigame "Deck Hands".
You and a friend play a game. You both pick 5 cards from a set containing numbers 1 through 10. The winner has the largest sum of 5 cards. Is it possible for you to tie? That is, can the sum of player 1's 5 cards equal the sum of the second player's 5 cards. If they tie, what are each of player's 5 cards? How many ways could they tie?
What are your thoughts on this problem?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Welcome to P.SE :) As it stands, I believe this puzzle is too straightforward to be of much interest. A way to give more depth to the idea might be to change the deck of cards. For example, the deck consisting of the first ten odd numbers already make for a considerably more interesting puzzle (imo), while still being easy enough. :)

@TimSeifert I agree this was too low hanging fruit which happened to fall in my basket just before going to sleep. I can delete answer if you prefer so.

@bobble this is a puzzle I thought up. It was inspired by the Mario Party 7 minigame "Deck Hands".

FYI in original attributed minigame (where order seems to but does not matter) we have 13 cards and each player picks 3 cards leaving no less than 45360 ties with perhaps 1+3+7 = 2+4+5 the easiest one

@FirstNameLastName How about 4 way ties? I combined your logic on splitting up the sum among the players with mine (regarding parity) to narrow it down to 3 possible situations in which a 4 way tie could occur: when the 3 is not picked (each player's hands summing to 22), the 7 is not picked (hands summing to 21), or the game when the 11 is not picked (20). I found one 4 way tie for the 1st case, each player getting 5+7+10, 12+4+6, 11+9+2 and 13+1+8.

I found 3 way example by program (and amount 10 or 13 is another variable choice, of course). I do not claim to follow any generic algorithm. But original question at hand (amount 10 5 way) happened to be easy.


 total sum is odd so there is no way to tie


I might have the smooth brain, but I was only convinced myself there was no way to tie by checking all possible parities of the 2 hands and seeing they could never agree. (e.g one hands even other player's is odd for all 6 cases) How can you tell from just the total sum?
For example, say the card were 1 through 5 total summing 15 (an odd sum) but if the players pick 2 cards each 4 and 1 and 2 and 3 they could tie.

In your example n=5 is an odd number and players cannot pick same amount of cards adding up to all 5 as in case n=10 where both take 5=n/2 as you mandated. Now, for any n, sum=((n+1)*n)/2 (by well known Gauss formula) which must be odd. So for n even there is no way to tie splitting all cards in two equal amounts. Since that would split an odd total sum into sum of two equal sums which is not possible. Such sum must be even,

@tothemax How can you tell from just the total sum? The sum of the numbers 1-10 is odd (55).  If the players were to tie, they would (obviously!) each have half of that total.  But you can't divide an odd number in half.

@tothemax : if you estimate question or answer to be too trivial for PSE acceptance, so be it, please leave it as is, I would actually fully agree ... But if you think about taking a decision wrapping up, consider accepting anyway

@FirstNameLastName sorry, yeah, you got it! Didn't realize I had to accept it.

@tothemax : you did not have to accept it but I appreciate you did: happy 2025
